# Maven install build error - Path to Dependency

Tags: java, spring, maven, struts

I have gone to my directory where the project folders and files are and executed a `mvn clean` and `mvn install` and yet i get this:

```
   [INFO] Unable to find resource ‘org.eclipse.core:org.eclipse.core.commands:pom:3.5.0.I20090525-2000’ in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
    [INFO]-------
    [ERROR] BUILD ERROR
    [INFO]---------
    [INFO] Failed to resolve artifact.

Couldn’t find a version in [1.0.0-v20070606] to match range [1.0.0,2.0.0) org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:null from the specified remote repositories:
central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2),
ABC.Pricing.R2(http://mksrvsub.XXXXX/nexus/content/repositories/ABC.pricing.R2),
abc-snapshots(http://artifactory-tmp.xxxxx:8081/nexus/content/groups/repor),
abc123 (http://mksrvsub.XXXXX/nexus/content/repositories/Release),
andromeda (http://artifactory-tmp.xxxxxxx:8081/nexus/content/repositories/andromeda),

path to dependency:
com.xxx:MyServcies:jar:7.7.0-SNAPSHOT
com.xxx:MyBaseServcies:jar:7.7.0-SNAPSHOT
com.xxx:MyStrutsServcies:jar:7.7.0-SNAPSHOT
com.yyy.SomeSpecialService:jar:7.7.0-SNAPSHOT
org.eclipse:get:jar:3.2.100-v20070530
org.eclipse.core:runtime:jar:3.3.100-v20070530
```

project pom file: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19509627/pom.xml)

Info:
Java Version: 1.6.0_26

OS name: windows xp, verison: 5.1 arch:x86,

Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)

Comment: showing the pom.xml may help

Comment: added the pom file via dropbox link

Comment: try to delete the repository folder inside the m2 Maven directory and try to install again, it will be dowload again all and hope that now work...some time give this kind of problem...

Comment: @AndreaNobili deleting and `mvn clean` and `mvn install` still gave the same Path To Dependency error..

Comment: What's the maven version?

Comment: Apache Maven 2.2.1 (r801777; 2009-08-06 15:16:01-0400)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see Maven cannot resolve dependency org.eclipse.core.commands version 3.5.0.I20090525-2000. Repository http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 does not contain artifact with this version number. Therefore you have to add repository description in your pom file.

Something like:

```
<repositories>
<repository>
<id>jboss-deprecated-repository</id>
<name>JBoss Deprecated Maven Repository</name>
<url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/deprecated/</url>
</repository>
...
<repositories>
```

Also you can read https://community.jboss.org/wiki/MavenGettingStarted-Users