# Maven cannot find version for equinox eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I made sure that my `.m2` repository contains the offending `app-1.0.0-v20070606.jar` which is also the latest build from the official Equinox [page](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/equinox/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/index.php).

So when I do my `mvn install` on my command prompt, i get a `BUILD ERROR`: Failed to resolve artifact. Couldn't find a version in [1.0.0-v20070606] to match range [1.0.0,2.0.0) org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:null Couldn’t find a version in [1.0.0-v20070606] to match range [1.0.0,2.0.0) `org.eclipse.equinox:app:jar:null` from the specified remote repositories:
`central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)`

Is there something I am missing?

POM [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/19509627/AjaxServicesPom.xml)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven install build error - Path to Dependency](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588390/maven-install-build-error-path-to-dependency)

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a range and have a version number incompatible with the maven version range code.  Give the exact version explicitly.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen where can I edit the range and version number?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen POM link included now